# Install numpy with Miniconda when the anaconda repo is blocked

Tags: python, anaconda, package, firewall

At my new job, many websites are blocked for security issues. The preferred way to get Python is to ask for a rollout, but it contains only few packages and I cannot install new ones on top. I was told that requesting a new rollout could take up to several months (they are not used to workers using this kind of software where I work).

I successfully installed Miniconda3 but it seems I cannot access the standard repo for anaconda:

```
conda install numpy
```

gives

> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url
> https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json
> Elapsed: - An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
> [...] If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked,
> please file a support request with your network enigneering team.

and

```
pip install numpy
```

gives

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
> redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip.vencor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
> object at 0x000001B76C5058E0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out.
> (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/numpy/

I have never faced these kinds of problems and I am puzzled about how to solve it. Is there any workaround like changing the repo or retrieving and installing all my packages manually? How would I do this without admin privilages?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`conda-pack`](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/). I haven't used it myself but it seems to be straightforward. Create the environment on a system with internet, save this environment using `conda-pack` and clone the environment on your work machine. [Make sure that the OS on both the machines are the same](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/#caveats).

Another alternative you could explore - if you aren't adamant about using conda and just need scientific packages like `numpy`, `scipy` and `pandas` - is [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/) (only for Windows).